# Multiprocessing share variables (type self created)

Tags: python

I have a GUI where I want to do multiprocessing. My problem comes when i want to share a variable from a class that I had created.
I am trying to share it into the two modules that are running simultaneosly by using class multiprocessing.Queue([maxsize]). 
But it dosen't work...

```
sch=sched()
q=Queue()
q.put([sch])

def foo1():
   sch=q.get([sch])
   event=Event(8) #another class created
   sch.add_list(event)
   q.put([sch])
   time.sleep(12)

def foo2():
   time.sleep(4)
   sch=q.get([sch])
   q.put([sch])
   print(sch.event_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=foo1)
    p2 = Process(target=foo2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: _But it dosen't work..._ Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the Queue instance as argument to the processes.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def foo1(q):
   sch = q.get([sch])
   event = Event(8)
   sch.add_list(event)
   q.put([sch])
   time.sleep(12)

def foo2(q):
   time.sleep(4)
   sch = q.get([sch])
   q.put([sch])
   print(sch.event_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    sch = sched()
    q.put([sch])
    p1 = Process(target=foo1, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=foo2, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

When Python forks a new process it gets its own namespace, so it is not possible to access variables of your main program from within a child process.

If you want to share one object without passing it around through `Pipes` or `Queues`, you can also use Python `Manager` classes (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?#managers). A manager creates a shared object which can be accessed from child processes. I suppose, `sch` is a list, so I used `manager.list()` in my example. For other data types just check the Python docs.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def foo():
    sch = sch_shared  # Read from shared list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sch = sched()
    mgr = Manager()
    sch_shared = mgr.list(sch)  # Create a shared list and return proxy
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

Comment: foo1 and foo2 don't have any argument, and you are passing an argument?

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL: Thanks. I forgot to add that.

Comment: The fact is I just want to have this var updated on bouth processes, so I should pick the last item added on the queue. But I think that's not optimal but i can't find any other solution. Do u know any? Thanks